# Django HTTP responses are cached by Gunicorn

Tags: django, caching, gunicorn

I apologize for any mistakes made or dumb questions asked, but this is my first one here.

I tried to search for the solution, but wasn't able to. Here is what's going on.

I have Nginx + virtualenv + Gunicorn + Django project. Django is still in Debug mode.
The thing I can not figure out is why all my Django responses are hardly cached. E.g., if I request a certain Url/View with no URI parameters, it will show me exactly what is coded, but if I then pass predefined parameters, that should be giving me another result, however it still shows the previous one.

As far as I can see, each of such responses is being cached per each Gunicorn worker. So when I restart Gunicorn, I then can see the proper result, however that is also cached right away.

I also tried running Gunicorn with --debug option, but it looks like that is not the solution.

Does anybody know where should I dig to? Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:

If I put...

```
HttpResponse('abc')
```

at the very beginning of the view, server will sure give me that as response. If I then change it to...

```
HttpResponse('def')
```

the server will still give me 'abc' as a response until I restart Gunicorn in the virtualenv. When I restart Genicorn and check it gives me 'def', it will then be giving me 'def' all the time until I restart Gunicorn again.

Comment: Can you put some code, so we can help?

Comment: Victor, I've updated the post with a sample.

Comment: @CostantineIvankin I jus put an answer